# How can I convert from an overhead door to a man door?

Tags: doors, shed, garage-door

A property I purchased has a detached and pretty solid detached garage in the back on a raised cement foundation. It has running electricity and I have no need for it, so I'm considering turning it into an office space for myself.

The door is slides upward like a garage door, though I'd like a doorway a bit simpler for my office and I'm not sure how to convert this into something more practical... assuming I can at an affordable price.[image]

The picture doesn't show it well, but it's very spacious reaching back a good 30 feet.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but I'm curious: why do you call this a carport? Every carport I've ever seen has open walls, as shown here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carport. Why is this not a garage?

Comment: I think you're correct. I'll edit this post to read detached garage.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the walls are standard wood construction, with dimensional lumber, pulling out the door and putting in a standard entry door is fairly straightforward.

First take out the rolling door. It's best to do this in the reverse order that it was put in. Carefully remove / release the tension on any springs or lift assists that may be in place. If the door is a series of panels bolted together with hinges, start at the top and remove the bolts holding the top panel to the one down, and remove the rollers at the sides of the door. Set the panel down, and repeat with the next panel down.

Once the door is out of the way, remove the track and any other door bits.

Then you have a choice. You can leave the already framed / trimmed opening and put in a wall to house the new door set back a bit, or you can remove the trim and match the existing siding.

In either case, you'll have to frame up a smaller wall to fit in the opening with a new door header / opening, place some sill gasket material down, and fasten it to the slab and existing opening.

Once the temporary wall is up, you can sheath it, leaving the new door opening clear, and place siding over that.

Install the new door and hardware, and the space is enclosed.

You didn't mention what the inside of the structure is like. If you're considering turning it into an office, you might consider an air conditioner, drywall, and nice inside accouterments.

Comment: A window might also be nice in the "non-door" part of the new wall. Don't add drywall (if it's lacking) without adding insulation (which is probably sub-optimal even if there is some.)

Comment: The interior is the cement foundation inside with metal frames and the metal exterior all around. A wall with an AC unit is a good idea... I don't plan to make it my office, but I do plan to have a desk in there and some exercise equipment - couple of couches. Not sure what I'll do to the floor quite yet: carpet or area rugs most likely. Also, good comment on the insulation - I am planning to put that in before the drywall... definitely a must for this thing.